# Using Pregreplace on Multiple Simple Strings

Tags: php, preg-replace, head.js

I am trying to implement head.js to load all of my js files asynchronously.

To do this javascript files should be loaded in the following manner:

```
<script>head.js("file1.js")</script>
<script>head.js("file2.js")</script>
<script>head.js("file3.js")</script>
```

If my files were styled as normal like:

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
<script src="file3.js"></script>
```

I would be able to use something like this to get my desired result:

```
$pattern = '~\<script src=(.*?)\>~';
$replacement = '<script>head.js($1)>';
$html = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$html);
```

However at the moment I have a minifier on my installation that combines the javascript files into the following style:

```
<script src="http://mysite.com/js/file1.js,/js/file2.js,/js/file3.js"></script>
```

I am terrible with reg expressions...would anyone be able to help me out with a replacement pattern that would work convert it into the head.js format?

Almost forgot...the number of files is not limited to three, it will be more but the amount is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pattern = '!(\w+\.)+js!';
$html = '<script src="http://mysite.com/js/file1.js,/js/file2.js,/js/file3.js"></script>';
preg_match_all($pattern,$html, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => file1.js [1] => file2.js [2] => file3.js ) )
```

Your can get your first file like this: `print $match[0][0];`, second `print $match[0][1];` and so on.

Comment: I really like that, but unfortunately it cannot cope with multiple "." in a file name, for example jquery.min.js returns min.js

Comment: i edited the answer, now it copes with: jquery.min.js   jquery.min.max.js  jquery.js